# Devise way to redirect user to after_sign_in_path_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is there a Devise specific way of redirecting a role to the specified default page returned by `after_sign_in_path_for`? I have the following code in my application controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for resource
    dashboard_path
end
```

In a different controller, one which I do not want to be accessible after the role has signed in, I have the following code that utilizes a `before_action` to redirect the role. This code works correctly, but I feel like there is a better or Devise specific approach to doing this.

```
before_action :redirect_user_if_signed_in

def index
end

private
  def redirect_user_if_signed_in
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the *"devise-way"* is to use `authenticate`, `authenticated` and `unauthenticated` methods in your **config/routes.rb**

```
unauthenticated do
  get 'only-for-guests' => 'guests#index'
end

authenticated do
  get 'only-for-guests' => redirect('/dashboard')
end
```

There are more examples here: [Define resource actions that require authentication using routes.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb)